# Undefined Reference to File in CMake When Building a Library from Source

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I am relatively new to C and very new to using CMake to build from source. I found this library I would like to use on Github:

https://github.com/kolrabi/steamcontroller

I am currently having trouble building the example file in the repository just to make sure it is working. When I could not figure out how to change the build directory or avoid the added check at the top of the make file, I decided to edit it and remove it to see if that worked any better (this is my first time using CMake). After commenting out the top IF statement that throws an exception in the MakeLists.txt file (the first 3 lines of the MakeFiles.txt), it gives this error:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target SteamController
[ 11%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_linux.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_win32.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_feedback.c.o
[ 44%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_setup.c.o
[ 55%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_state.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object 
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_wireless.c.o
[ 77%] Linking C shared library cygSteamController-0.1.dll
CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/steamcontroller_feedback.c.o:steamcontroller_feedback.c:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `SteamController_HIDSetFeatureReport'

...

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/build.make:225: 
cygSteamController-0.1.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/SteamController.dir/all] 
Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:128: all] Error 2
```

I believe it has something to do with the headder file common.h not getting included in the library due to the structs the error is referencing being included in that file, although I am not sure as this is not my project. Thank you in advance for your help.

I am trying to include support for a Steam controller in my own C programs once I can get the example running.

Here is some of the code pertaining to the example and the CMake File:

Edited CMakeLists.txt (Top IF statement has been commented out):

```
#IF                      ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
#  MESSAGE               ( FATAL_ERROR "Prevented in-tree built. Please create a build directory outside of the source code and call cmake from there" )
#ENDIF                   ( )

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED  ( VERSION 2.6 )
PROJECT                 ( LibSteamController C )

IF                      ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC )
  SET                   ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror" )
ELSEIF                  ( MSVC )
  SET                   ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /W4 /WX" )
ENDIF                   ( )

OPTION                  ( BUILD_STATIC_LIB       "Build static library"         FALSE )

SET                     ( SOURCES
                          steamcontroller_linux.c
                          steamcontroller_win32.c

                          steamcontroller_feedback.c
                          steamcontroller_setup.c
                          steamcontroller_state.c
                          steamcontroller_wireless.c
                        )

IF                      ( BUILD_STATIC_LIB )
  ADD_LIBRARY           ( SteamController STATIC ${SOURCES} )
ELSE                    ( )
  ADD_LIBRARY           ( SteamController SHARED ${SOURCES} )

  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES ( SteamController  PROPERTIES
                          VERSION     "0.1.2"
                          SOVERSION   "0.1" )
ENDIF                   ( )

ADD_DEFINITIONS         ( -DSTEAMCONTROLLER_BUILDING_LIBRARY ) 

IF                      ( WIN32 )
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( SteamController setupapi hid )
ENDIF                   ( )

ADD_EXECUTABLE          ( SteamControllerExample example.c )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES   ( SteamControllerExample SteamController )

INSTALL                 ( TARGETS SteamController
                          RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
                          LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
                          ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
                        )

INSTALL                 ( FILES       steamcontroller.h
                          DESTINATION include
                        )
```

example.c:

```
#include "steamcontroller.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  SteamControllerDeviceEnum *pEnum = SteamController_EnumControllerDevices();
  while (pEnum) {
    SteamControllerEvent event;
    SteamControllerDevice *pDevice = SteamController_Open(pEnum);
    if (pDevice) {  

      ... Test Connection ...

      SteamController_Close(pDevice);
    }
    pEnum = SteamController_NextControllerDevice(pEnum);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

common.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if _MSC_VER
#define inline __inline
#endif

void Debug_DumpHex(const void *pData, size_t count);

#define USB_VID_VALVE                               0x28de
#define USB_PID_STEAMCONTROLLER_WIRED               0x1102
#define USB_PID_STEAMCONTROLLER_WIRELESS            0x1142
#define USB_PID_STEAMCONTROLLER_DONGLE_BOOTLOADER   0x1042

#define STEAMCONTROLLER_CLEAR_MAPPINGS             0x81 // 1000 0001
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_GET_ATTRIBUTES             0x83 // 1000 0011
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_UNKNOWN_85                 0x85 // 1000 0101
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_SET_SETTINGS               0x87 // 1000 0111 // seems to reset config
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_UNKNOWN_8E                 0x8E // 1000 1110
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_TRIGGER_HAPTIC_PULSE       0x8F // 1000 1111
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_START_BOOTLOADER           0x90 // 1001 0000
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_SET_PRNG_ENTROPY           0x96 // 1001 0110
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_TURN_OFF_CONTROLLER        0x9F // 1001 1111
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_DONGLE_GET_VERSION         0xA1 // 1010 0001
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_ENABLE_PAIRING             0xAD // 1010 1101
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_GET_STRING_ATTRIBUTE       0xAE // 1010 1110
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_UNKNOWN_B1                 0xB1 // 1011 0001
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_DISCONNECT_DEVICE          0xB2 // 1011 0010
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_COMMIT_DEVICE              0xB3 // 1011 0011
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_DONGLE_GET_WIRELESS_STATE  0xB4 // 1011 0100
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_PLAY_MELODY                0xB6 // 1011 0110
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_GET_CHIPID                 0xBA // 1011 1010
#define STEAMCONTROLLER_WRITE_EEPROM               0xC1 // 1100 0001

typedef struct {
  uint8_t reportPage;
  uint8_t featureId;
  uint8_t dataLen;
  uint8_t data[62];
} SteamController_HIDFeatureReport;

bool SteamController_HIDSetFeatureReport(const SteamControllerDevice *pDevice, SteamController_HIDFeatureReport *pReport);
bool SteamController_HIDGetFeatureReport(const SteamControllerDevice *pDevice, SteamController_HIDFeatureReport *pReport);

bool    SteamController_Initialize(const SteamControllerDevice *pDevice);
uint8_t SteamController_ReadRaw(const SteamControllerDevice *pDevice, uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t maxLen);


static inline uint8_t LowByte(uint16_t value)   { return value & 0xff; }
static inline uint8_t HighByte(uint16_t value)  { return (value >> 8) & 0xff; }

static inline void StoreU16(uint8_t *pDestination, uint16_t value) {
  pDestination[0] = (value >> 0) & 0xff;
  pDestination[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xff;
}

static inline void StoreU32(uint8_t *pDestination, uint32_t value) {
  pDestination[0] = (value >>  0) & 0xff;
  pDestination[1] = (value >>  8) & 0xff;
  pDestination[2] = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
  pDestination[3] = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the **code**, which is related to the problem, to be **in the question post** itself; *link* to the outer repo is *insufficient*. Please, add your code into the question post, preferrable in form of [mcve].

Comment: ld error aren't usually caused by headers. Please include how the linker is invoked

Comment: You show the header file, where function `SteamController_HIDSetFeatureReport` is **declared**. But where the function is **defined** (with body, `{...}`)? The linker complains exactly about the function's definition, which it cannot find.

Comment: No reason to comment out that check.  You just create a build directory and call cmake from there.  It is in the error message.  Also `cmake --help` prints `cmake [options] <path-to-source>`.